# Moving Data from ArrayList in Second activity to main activity - android

Tags: java, android

I want to move data from an ArrayList in a second activity to my main activity.

This is my main.java file

````
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultcode, data);


   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   textView = findViewById(R.id.callingOrder);
   ArrayList<String> numbersList = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("key");
   textView.setText(String.valueOf(numbersList));```
````

```
public void onBackPressed(){


Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("key", sandwichOrder);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

the second.java file above ^

I only get a null message on my xml file. Point is to move the data when I press the back arrow button.

Comment: please post the fulls stack trace of the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line, you're looking in the wrong `Intent`:

> ```
> ArrayList<String> numbersList = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("key");
> ```

`getIntent()` will return the Intent that was used to start your activity. Anything you pass "back" with `setResult()` will be in the `data` parameter to `onActivityResult()`. So write this instead:

```
ArrayList<String> numbersList = (ArrayList<String>) data.getSerializableExtra("key");
```